# Javascript forEach loops only last value of an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am using creating a todoApp.

The function constructor accepts task list as array and I loop through them and dynamically create fields via `forEach` loop. However, it only loops the last value of that array.

How can I fix this?

```js
class TodoApp {
 constructor(rootApp, todoTasks) {
  this.rootApp = rootApp;
  this.todoTasks = todoTasks;
  this.todoStatus = false;
 }
 todoHandler() {
  const label = document.createElement('label');
  const radio = document.createElement('input');
  const brTag = document.createElement('br');

  if(Object.prototype.toString.call(this.todoTasks) === '[object Array]') {
   this.todoTasks.forEach((el, id) => {
    label.innerText = el;
    radio.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
    radio.value = id;
    this.rootApp.appendChild(radio);
    this.rootApp.appendChild(label);
   });
  } else {
   throw new Error('Tasks should be of type Array');
  }
 }
}

let tasks = new TodoApp(
  document.getElementById('todoLister'),
  [
   'Get Up',
   'Brush Teeth',
   'Eat Breakfast',
   'Wear Uniform',
   'Goto School'
  ]
 );
tasks.todoHandler();
```

```html
<div id="todoLister">

</div>
```

Comment: You only create a single `<label>`, a single `<input>`, a single `<br>`. Why do you expect to see multiple elements?

Comment: ... Put `const label` inside the loop

Comment: My bad! Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only creating one label, radio and `<br>` tag. So each iteration of the loop is overwriting the values set by the previous iteration, meaning that only the last values persist.

To solve, simply create a new label, radio and `<br>` tag inside each loop iteration:

```js
class TodoApp {
 constructor(rootApp, todoTasks) {
  this.rootApp = rootApp;
  this.todoTasks = todoTasks;
  this.todoStatus = false;
 }
 todoHandler() {
  if(Object.prototype.toString.call(this.todoTasks) === '[object Array]') {
   this.todoTasks.forEach((el, id) => {
                            const label = document.createElement('label');
                            const radio = document.createElement('input');
                            const brTag = document.createElement('br');

       label.innerText = el;
       radio.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
       radio.value = id;
       this.rootApp.appendChild(radio);
       this.rootApp.appendChild(label);
       this.rootApp.appendChild(brTag);
   });
  } else {
   throw new Error('Tasks should be of type Array');
  }
 }
}

let tasks = new TodoApp(
  document.getElementById('todoLister'),
  [
   'Get Up',
   'Brush Teeth',
   'Eat Breakfast',
   'Wear Uniform',
   'Goto School'
  ]
 );
tasks.todoHandler();
```

```html
<div id="todoLister">

</div>
```

Comment: Marking as answer in 7 minutes :)